# make multilevel array from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have this array in an example, how can i get the same result from query from database?, i need to replace the values which the values of the database.

```
$data = array(
array(
    'qty' => 1,
    'Price' => 1.00,
    'total' => 1.00
),
array(
    'qty' => 2,
    'Price' => 1.00,
    'total' => 2.00
),
array(
    'qty' => 3,
    'Price' => 1.00,
    'total' => 3.00
)

);
```

then in the example use the nusoap lib

```
foreach($data as $concept) {
$par['Concepts'][] = new soapval('Concept', 'Concept', $concept);
}
```

so i need to call the query:

```
$query_data_cot = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id='1'"); 

while($data_quote=mysql_fetch_array($query_data_cot)){
$conceptosDatos[]["qty"]=$data_quote['qty'];
$conceptosDatos[]["Price"]=$data_quote['price'];
$conceptosDatos[]["total"]=$data_quote['total'];
}
```

but when i do these i got an error

```
 Error: Array ( [faultcode] => soap:Server [faultstring] => Server was unable to process request. --->
```

thank you

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i got this error        Error: Array ( [faultcode] => soap:Server [faultstring] => Server was unable to process request. --->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you use `$conceptosDatos[]...` the `[]` will create a new subarray. So your result will be something like this

```
array(
    array('qty' => ..),
    array('Price' => ..),
    array('total' => ...),
    array('qty' => ..),
    array('Price' => ..),
    array('total' => ...),
    ...
)
```

Instead you need to create a new subarray only for a whole set, so use something like this

```
$query_data_cot = mysql_query("SELECT qty, price, total FROM data WHERE id='1'"); 
while($data_quote=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_data_cot)){
    $conceptosDatos[] = $data_quote;
}
```

Of course you could also do it like this

```
$query_data_cot = mysql_query("SELECT qty, price, total FROM data WHERE id='1'"); 
while($data_quote=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_data_cot)){
    $conceptosDatos[] = array(
        'qty' => $data_quote['qty'],
        'Price' => $data_quote['price'],
        'total' => $data_quote['total'],
    );
}
```

But why write every field if you're going to copy the whole array anyway?

If you need to use different names (as in your example `price` and `Price`), you can either change your db schema or use aliases in your query, giving you this code:

```
$query_data_cot = mysql_query("SELECT qty, price AS Price, total FROM data WHERE id='1'"); 
while($data_quote=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_data_cot)){
    $conceptosDatos[] = $data_quote;
}
```

This has the advantage that if you wish to modify your code in the future, you'd only need to modify the query (and could probably encapsulate this logic inside a function) - so less work for future you.

---

By the way, did you see the big red box in the manual on all `mysql_*` methods's sites? It's deprecated and PDO as well as MySQLi are way better alternatives. [This helps decide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) what to use.

Comment: _Why write every field_? For some reason, he has different keys in his new array than the table field names ('Price' vs. 'price').

Comment: @Barmar Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , `while($data_quote=mysql_fetch_array($query_data_cot , MYSQL_ASSOC ))` , as you are retrieving the `$data` as an associative array .

Comment: OP could simply do `mysql_fetch_assoc` as well.

Comment: Also default is `MYSQL_BOTH`, so leaving it to said default shouldn't cause an error

Answer (score 0):

Each assignment line in your loop is creating a new element of the `$conceptDatos` array, not filling in a different element of the same element. So your array looks like:

```
array(
    array('qty' => 1),
    array('Price' => 1.0),
    array('total' => 1.0),
    array('qty' => 2),
    array('Price' => 1.0),
    array('total' => 1.0),
    ...
)
```

Your loop shoud be:

```
while($data_quote=mysql_fetch_array($query_data_cot)){
    $conceptDatos[] = array(
        'qty' => $data_quote['qty'],
        'Price' => $data_quote['price'],
        'total' => $data_quote['total']
    );
}
```